# How to ignore some directories with find-grep-dired?

Tags: dired, grep, find-dired, find

When I search with `find-grep-dired` it also searches `/Library/` directory and finds hundreds of cached links. Is there a way to ignore `/Library/` directory?

I found [this](https://%20https://mindlev.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/excluding-directories-from-rgrep-in-emacs/) :

```
M-x customize-option
<return>
grep-find-ignored-directories
```

But it didn't work for me. Is `grep-find-ignored-directories` depracated?

I will remove my documents file from the root directory eventually so I don't have to search the entire disc but a solution now would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use library [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) (see also [Locate Files Anywhere](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere)), then you can exclude any number of paths, and you can limit the depth.

> **`find-grep-dired`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar search find find-grep-dired, menu-bar subdir find find-grep-dired`.
>
> `(find-grep-dired DIR REGEXP &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)`
>
> Use Dired on the list of files in `DIR` whose contents match `REGEXP`.
>
> The `find` command run (after changing into `DIR`) is essentially this,
> where `LS-SWITCHES` is `(car find-ls-option)`:
>
> ```
> find . \( -type f -exec grep grep-program find-grep-options \
>      -e REGEXP {} \; \) LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> Thus `REGEXP` can also contain additional grep options.
>
> Optional arg `DEPTH-LIMITS` is a list `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)` of the
> minimum and maximum depths.  If `nil`, search directory tree under `DIR`.
>
> **Optional arg `EXCLUDED-PATHS` is a list of strings that match paths to
> exclude from the search.  If `nil`, search all directories.
>
> When both optional args are non-`nil`, the `find` command run is this:
>
> ```
> find .
>      -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
>      \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
>      -prune -o -exec grep-program find-grep-options -e REGEXP {} \;
>      LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> where `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.